# On the determination of ambiguous ideal class of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{m})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{n},\zeta_5)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ the $5^{th}$ cyclotomic fields, we now that $[L:K] = 5$ and  $\textrm{Gal}(L/K) = \langle \sigma \rangle$ so we call $\mathcal{A}$ an ambigous ideal class of the extension $L/K$ if and only if $\mathcal{A}^{\sigma}= \mathcal{A}$.

My question is how to prove using that  $\sigma^4+\sigma^3+\sigma^2+\sigma+1 = 0$ that it exist a non trivial ambiguous ideal class??

Comment: The trivial class is ambigous. Can you precise your question ?

Comment: is there any other non trivial ambigous class, in other way I need to prove that the rank of group of ambigous ideal classes grather than 1.

Comment: for exemple in the case of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n},\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ we have $\sigma^3=1$ and $ \sigma^2+\sigma+1=0$ and we have $\mathcal{A}^{3}=\mathcal{A}$, so we prouve that $\mathcal{A}^{\sigma-1}$ is ambigous. I need to do the same for the case of 5

Comment: This is most definitely not an "elementary number theory" question. And "arithmetic" fells like a stretch to me, but I'm leaving that one in.

Comment: Now posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [On the determination of ambiguous ideal class of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{m})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5))$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/348147). When [meta-tag:cross-posting], it is [recommended to link to the other copies](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088).

Answer (score 2):

The ideal class of $O_L$ is represented by a product of unramified prime ideals $$I=\prod_j P_j$$ above distinct prime ideals $\pi_j O_K$ $$\pi_j O_L=\prod_{i=1}^{c_j} P_{i,j} = \prod_{i=0}^{c_j-1} \sigma^i(P_j)$$ (the LHS is principal because $O_K=\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ is a PID)

and $c_j\ne 1$ implies $P_j$ is comaximal to $\sigma(P_j)$ thus $I=\sigma(I)$ implies each $c_j=1$ ie. $I  = (\prod_j \pi_j)$ is principal, thus only the principal ideal class is self conjugate.

Comment: your proof is valid in general case, my question is to find an explicit non trivial class which is ambigous, for exemple in the case of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n},\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ we have $\sigma^3=1$ and $ \sigma^2+\sigma+1=0$ and we have $\mathcal{A}^{3}=\mathcal{A}$, so we prouve that $\mathcal{A}^{\sigma-1}$ is ambigous. I need to do the same for the case of 5

Comment: It cannot happen if $O_K$ is a PID, try with $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}), L= \Bbb{Q}((-5)^{1/4})$ and $I= (2,(-5)^{1/4}-1)$ or $J= (3,\sqrt{-5}+1)$

Comment: but in the cubic case it happen and $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID